# Making \cite behave like \textcite in biblatex

Tags: latex, biblatex

I use biblatex and I basically use `\textcite` all the time. It would be quicker (and allow me to use some emacs reftex macros) if I could make `\cite` display like `\textcite` does. I use the `style=apa` option, so what this amounts to is I want `\cite` to do this: "Author (1999)" whereas it currently does this: "Author, 1999".

How do I redfine `\cite` to do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be as simple as just `\let\cite\textcite` -- that defines `\cite` to have the same value as `\textcite` has at the point of definition.

Comment: Just before this I added an alias for `\cite` so that if I did need it, I'd be able to use it.
`\let\npcite\cite`